# Multiple cross references (not citations)

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I'm trying to refer to multiple references (not citations) at once and I can't figure out how to do it, and have it display the way I want. Essentially I want to refer to figures 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 and have it display as "Figures 1.4-6." It would appear that if I use the 'cleveref' package, the following code will get me half way there:

```
Figures \labelcref{fig:xxx,fig:yyy,fig:zzz}.
```

This will display as "Figures 1.4 to 1.6". How do I modify the default format so that it will display as "Figures 1.4-6"?

Comment: The `cleveref` package is perfect for your needs. Instead of `Figures \ref{fig:xxx,fig:yyy,fig:zzz}`, you'd write `\cref{fig:xxx,fig:yyy,fig:zzz}`. The package even lets you tailor the output so that it'll say `Figures 1.4--6` rather than `Figures 1.4--1.6`.

Comment: The default output is "Figures 1.4 to 1.6". Is there a way to modify this so it instead displays as "Figures 1.4-6"?

Comment: There are multiple possible range-related adjustments. Please see the package's user guide for these possibilities.

Comment: It's not the most legible document for a newbie. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you load the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/) package and use the method provided in section 9 of the package's user guide to get the desired formatting of cross-references to multiple, consecutive items.

Here's a compilable example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}  % just for this example
\setcounter{figure}{3}   % ditto

\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\label{fig:a}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{Another figure}\label{fig:b}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{Still another figure}\label{fig:c}\end{figure}

\cref{fig:a,fig:b,fig:c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried adding the second and third line to my preamble, but I just get errors once I start using \cref in my document (with no instance of \cref or \labelcref it compiled fine). The error says something about an undefined control sequence.

Comment: @Ulysses -- Which TeX distribution and which version of the `cleveref` package is on your system?